# What is a non-interactive service account?

Tags: active-directory, iis

Trying to get a clear understanding of what makes a AD domain service account non-interactive and how this is done?

I require a service e account with "logon as a service" and "logon as a batch" for a service account on a IIS box.

Comment: I Googled your title and found: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/noninteractive-authentication and

Answer (score 2):

Wha is an interactive logon ?

> An interactive logon to a computer can be performed either locally,
>   when the user has direct physical access, or remotely, through
>   Terminal Services, in which case the logon is further qualified as
>   remote interactive. After an interactive logon, Windows runs
>   applications on the user’s behalf and the user can interact with those
>   applications.
>
> Users can perform an interactive logon by logging on to a computer
>   using a local user account or by using their domain account.

Please read that blog about Managed service account. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/09/10/managed-service-accounts-understanding-implementing-best-practices-and-troubleshooting/

> The Windows Server 2008 R2 AD Schema introduces a new object class
>   called msDS-ManagedServiceAccount. Create an MSA, examine its
>   objectClass attribute, and notice the object has an interesting object
>   class inheritance structure:
>
> Computer
>
> msDS-ManagedServiceAccount
>
> organizationalPerson
>
> Top
>
> User
>
> The object is a user and a computer at the same time, just like a
>   computer account. But it does not have an object class of person like
>   a computer account typically would; instead it has
>   msDS-ManagedServiceAccount. MSA’s inherit from a parent object class
>   of “Computer”, but they are also users. MSA objects do not contain new
>   attributes from the Win2008 R2 schema update.

If you ask as you wish to make a service account, please see:

For your question, if a managed account is not what you look for, you can create a non-interactive account by creating a GPO that set that; Computer Configuration/Windows settings/Local Policies/User Right Assignement, and you deny the user account the Log On right. (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/deny-log-on-locally). That way that account will only be able to be used for services